# How to pass value for the JavaScript statements?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a value to a Javascript Statement. Is it possible?
For Example :

```
function Show(msg, Id, Msgtype) { // I need to pass this Id argument to below javascript innerHtml statement
  var strVar = "";
  strVar = "Hello" + Msgtype + " <i class='icon-remove close'></i> " + msg + "</div>";
  document.getElementById("???").innerHTML = strVar; // ??? should be the Id above in the function arguments
}
```

Or in other way, how can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: `document.getElementById(Id).innerHTML = strVar`?

Comment: As an aside: `strVar = "Hello" + Msgtype + " <i class='icon-remove close'></i> " + msg + "</div>";` has a close div tag but no open div tag. Not sure how pretty that will look off the top of my head. If you're going to add inner HTML, you should try to make sure close and open tags match up in there for sanity.

Comment: By open the <div> is not a concern for my problem.. But Id can be directly pass into the Javascript Statement. I thought about the quotes before and after of the Id :(.. Now it is working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `Id`, like this

```
document.getElementById(Id).innerHTML = strVar;
```